# how to retain the classic asp page after clicking on submit button( while validation error occurs)

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

In my asp page i have a checkbox and table(contains 5 tds).while page loading checkbox should be unchecked and only one "td" should appear in the table.After Clicking checkbox only second Td will appear.After that any validation error occurs while clicking on submit button the page should be retained only.But it's not working

Comment: How do you expect help without posting at least a basic example of what you have tried? [Using sessions to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36859821/692942) is just going to hurt the performance of the web app when passing via the `Session` object is unnecessary.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would suggest using Sessions. Also 1 page to get input , 1 page to process input.

View Bit(index.asp)

```
<input name="username" type="text" value="<%=session("username")%>
 <%
   if Session("error")=true then  
    response.write("Username cannot be blank") end if
 %>
```

Process Bit (index_process.asp)

```
<% 
   'Set error to false first everytime processed.
    Session("error") = false 
    if Session("username) = "" then
      Session("error") = true
    end if

   if Session("error") = true then
    ' If error is true , redirect back to index.asp
     response.redirect("index.asp")
   else 
     response.redirect("success_page.asp")
   endif

 %>
```

Since the input has been set to session , all of it will remain even when redirected back from the processing page . Just dont forget to clear the appropriate session data when its not needed anymore.

Comment: Bloating the session is unnecessary, first mistake many make. Simpler to just `POST` to the same page so all the `Request.Form` values are available inside the page again *(after any processing, saving to database etc)* then handle them accordingly.

Comment: While request.form will handle it most of the time , it is very messy to include combine both your form processing and form page on the same file. This invalidates post values. I handle a classic asp project with over 300 pages which gets monthly visitors of over 10000 while using what Lanky considers "Session Bloating" and it does not in any way cause any noticeable decrease in performance.

Comment: I don't see how it's in any way messy to include both the form and the code to process it in the same file. "Invalidates post values"? Eh?

Comment: Please post an answer using POST or another method you find cleaner if youre disagreeing with me. What youre commenting isnt helpful at all to users who dont not want to use the method i suggested